# Trigger change issue in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where I have multiple rows, one of the columns being an input for the charge. The html is below:

```
<tbody>
                    @foreach($shipment_details as $sd)
                        <tr style="height:40px" tr id="row{{$sd->id}}">
                            <td style="width:8%;text-align:center;">
                            <input type="text" id="piecesNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="No. Pieces" required name="shipment_details[{{$sd->id}}][piecesNumber]" value="{{$sd->pieces_number}}">
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16%;text-align:center;">
                            <select id="pieces_type" class="form-control full-width" required name="shipment_details[{{$sd->id}}][piecesType]">
                                @foreach($cPiecetypes as $cPt)
                                    <option value="{{$cPt->id}}"
                                     @if ($sd->pieces_type == $cPt->id) selected="selected" 
                                     @endif>{{$cPt->label}}</option>
                                @endforeach

                            </select>    
                            </td>
                            <td>
                             <select id="pieces_type" class="form-control full-width" required name="shipment_details[{{$sd->id}}][rateType]">
                                @foreach($cRatetypes as $cRt)
                                    <option value="{{$cRt->id}}"
                                     @if ($sd->rate_type == $cRt->id) selected="selected" 
                                     @endif>{{$cRt->label}}</option>
                                @endforeach

                            </select>

                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                            <input type="text" id="weight" class="form-control" placeholder="Weight" required name="shipment_details[{{$sd->id}}][weight]" value="{{$sd->weight}}">

                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">

                            <select id="hazmat" class="form-control full-width" required name="shipment_details[{{$sd->id}}][hazmat]">

                                    <option value="0"
                                     @if ($sd->hazmat = 0) selected="selected" 
                                     @endif>No</option>
                                     <option value="1"
                                     @if ($sd->hazmat = 1) selected="selected" 
                                     @endif>Yes</option>

                            </select>

                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                            <input type="text" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" required name="shipment_details[{{$sd->id}}][description]" value="{{$sd->description}}">

                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                            <input type="text" id="charge" class="form-control charges" placeholder="Charge" required name="shipment_details[{{$sd->id}}][charge]" value="{{$sd->charge}}">
                            </td>
                            <td><button type="button" name="removeExisting" id="{{$sd->id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn_removeExisting">X</button></td>
                </tr>

                    @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

As you see, there is a button at the end of reach row with the class of "btn_removeExisting" which connects to this script:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_removeExisting', function(){  
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
       $( '.charges' ).trigger( 'change' );
       alert('removeExisting');
  });
```

The alert is only there to notify me that the script has completed correctly, which is where my problem is. By pressing the button, it correctly deletes the correct row, and alerts me, but the trigger in the middle is where my problem originates.

The script regarding my change of charge trigger:

```
$(document).on('change', '.charges', function() {
    var sum = 0.00;
    $('.charges').each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();  
    });
    $('input[name^="freightBillSubtotal"]').val(sum.toFixed(2));
    calcTotal();
});
```

Now what's odd is if I just change a charge input, the code works, so if I change the charge on one line from 10.00 to 0.00, the subtotal subtracts 10.00. But for some reason it won't do the same for when an entire row (and it's specific charge) is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to trigger events manually like that, it is better to make a function and call it from both events:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_removeExisting', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  calcSum();
  alert('removeExisting');
});
$(document).on('change', '.charges', calcSum);

function calcSum() {
  var sum = 0.00;
  $('.charges').each(function() {
    sum += $(this).val();
  });
  $('input[name^="freightBillSubtotal"]').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  calcTotal();
});
```

Note: I assumed there was a harmless typo on your line:

```
sum += +$(this).val();
```

so I changed it to:

```
sum += $(this).val();
```